# Testing tools for frontend

Tags: testing, web, frontend, traffic

Does someone know any frontend **testing tools** for *simulating a lot of users activity* in different scenarios.
I need to test how an application will behave, when used by many people.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use selenium web-driver with a framework like TestNG to test a web app or website front-end and then pass in different parameter values for simulating different users. TestNG provides good annotation and test structure as well. Such as before and after methods.

Selenium Web-driver can be found here and its open source and easy to set up: http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/

TestNG framework provides a good test runner and HTML reports.
http://testng.org/doc/index.html

Also be worth looking at page object model for maintainable and reliable tests.